# ¿Como bloquear input despues de que tenga un valor?

Tags: javascript, grails

Estoy tratando que un input de tipo text datapicker se ponga en estado disbled después de que este tenga un valor el input es el siguente:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 cedula1">
  <label for="" class="control-label">Fecha de detención</label>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker1"value="${detencion}" class="form-control" name="fechaDetencion" placeholder="Selecciona la fecha" autocomplete="false">
</div>
```

Mientras no tenga un dato guardado este habilitado y cuando ya tenga un valor se desabilite. creo que es muy sencillo pero me esta costando algo de trabajo.

es el script del datapicker

```
$( function() {
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });} );
```

estas fechas se muestran en base a un g:select de grails y otro de mis conflictos igual es que si asigno un estatus al recargar la pagina se muestran todas las fechas de los otros estatus

```
$('#select').on('change',function(){
    var selectValor = $(this).val();               

    if (selectValor == '1') {
    $('.cedula').hide();
    }else {
    $('.cedula').hide();                    
        }
     });
```

Comment: estas usando jquery o alguna libreria en especial?

Comment: si, estoy con jquery,

Comment: Podrías poner el código que llevas hasta el momento, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu código javascript podrías usar algo así

```
$("#datapicker1").change(function(){
    if($('#datepicker1').val() != "")
    {
          $('#datepicker1').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Si me funcionó amigo, para solucionar lo del valor del input, gracias